# Attach program's bitcode to it's binary

Tags: llvm

Is there a pass or something in LLVM, that would serialize given `llvm::Module` into the binary form and then put this data into the source module? So when i link it into binary, i would end up with a bitcode representation of compiled code being linked with native code inside single file?

If not, can you give some advices on how to implement this?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? Some runtime profile-based late optimisation? How are you going to access that module?

Comment: I think, pointer to bitcode can be exported like string constant or just `extern void * m`. I'd use this pointer to deserialize it to `llvm::Module *` at the native level.

Comment: And what would you do with it after deserialisation?

Comment: Why does it matter? Analyze it and use analysis result in the program.

Comment: I cannot think of any scenario when you'll need the bitcode in the same binary file. You can always load it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is partially implemented in Clang/LLVM now and is called [ThinLTO](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-August/089222.html). It is now possible to run `clang -c -emit-llvm -flto=thin source.cpp` and this would produce a LLVM bitcode file with same bitcode embedded in it. Support for writing native object file with embedded bitcode is being worked on.